Is it correct to say "he gave me a bookshelf" or "he gave me bookshelves"?
The dictionary says a bookshelf is a shelf that you keep books on
My dad gave me this one which has 5 shelves:

What is this whole thing called? a bookshelf or bookshelves
Is it correct to say "he gave me a bookshelf" or "he gave me bookshelves"?

A bookshelf is a single shelf (horizontal plank of wood). Bookshelves plural means one or more units.

+1 A good question. I don't understand why a negative mark is given. The question is also popular 71 views in a day.

Ref. Collins dictionary meaning,
bookshelf in British English NOUN.
a piece of furniture consisting of a shelf or shelves for books.

Bookshelves is ambiguous, but so would be bookshelf. The ambiguity can be avoided by referring to the thing your father gave you as a bookcase.

Or a set of bookshelves.

A bookshelf may have many shelves.

Ref. Collins dictionary meaning,
bookshelf in British English NOUN.
a piece of furniture consisting of a shelf or shelves for books. collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bookshelf –

Can you use the word "bookcase" for the one your dad gave.
What Is A Bookcase?




Generally, a bookcase is a large, standalone piece of furniture with a number of shelves for storing things. A bookcase, as opposed to a bookshelf, frequently features doors that can be closed to protect your items from dust. In addition to being taller than bookshelves, bookcases have several shelves inside of them.
Ref. https://www.maximfurniture.com.my/bookshelf-vs-bookcase-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-choose/

You can call your item bookshelf because it is is commonly used interchangeably to mean a furniture having many shelves. Each row in a bookshelf is also called a "tier". If you call it "bookshelves". It sounds funny to say, " My dad gave me "a bookshelves".


Bookshelves come in tiers, with each row of shelves called a shelf or tier.
Her bookshelf has five tiers, full of science fiction novels.
https://www.wordupapp.co/dictionary/bookshelf

So it can be called "a bookshelf", "a bookshelf cabinet" or "a bookcase".

The advert you show here calls that furniture item a "Bookshelf Cabinet", not a "Bookshelf". The word bookshelf is not used to mean a bookcase or other item with multiple shelves.

@RosieF This is from Amazon. They mentioned bookshelf also. "A bookshelf' is a term popularly used for a set of bookshelves. I am unaware if it is unacceptable or inappropriate in some countries.

I agree with that. Referring to the whole furniture item as a bookshelf is common.

@RosieF I don't know where you live, but it definitely is for me. "Bookcase" isn't in my vernacular. The bookshelf is the unit of furniture, and the individual levels are shelves.

@JamesMathai Amazon is not a good source for English language, its best use is to show mangled english examples.

@WendyG How about Collins dictionary meaning, which says bookshelf is a piece of furniture.
bookshelf
in British English
NOUN
a piece of furniture consisting of a shelf or shelves for books.
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bookshelf

@JamesMathai It was just a warning not to rely on amazon for your examples.

@WendyG It made me do more research and I found in Collins dictionary. I am in the group just to learn new words and get knowledge.  I feel obliged when someone points my mistakes.

@JamesMathai, sorry I misread the tone of your comment
